# How to navigate from detail page to second master page SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have 2 master pages & a detail page. On Master 1 page, I have List items, On clicking one, it will navigate to 2nd Master page. There i have some selections & a button to navigate to detail page. I tried to navigate from detail page to 2nd Master page. But i can't make it. I goes straight to 1st Master Page. How can i achieve this?. Here is my view structure.

`<SplitApp id="MyApp" mode="HideMode" >
    <masterPages>
        <Page id="master1">
          <content>
          ....(List item)....
          </content>
        </Page>
        <Page id="master2">
          <content>
          ....(contents in fragment)....
          </content>
        </Page>
    </masterPages>
    <detailPages title="Detail">
        <mvc:XMLView viewName="demo.view.Detail"/>
    </detailPages>
</SplitApp>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a reference to your app control, and using its method `.toMaster(target)` you could navigate to any master page, including 'master2'. E.g.:

```
    this.byId("MyApp").toMaster(this.createId("master2"));
```

Have a look at this jsbin to see this in action:
http://jsbin.com/xocavo/1/edit?html,output